# How can I get a reference to a CodeMirror instance in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

The documentation indicates that there is a CodeMirror instance in the CodeEditorWrapper instance: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/notebook.html?highlight=codemirror#widget-hierarchy

I found an `editor` property on the CodeEditorWrapper instance. I thought it might be a CodeMirror instance like the one described here: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html, but it appears that it’s not.

How can I get a reference to a CodeMirror instance in JupyterLab?

I am trying to do what is described here:  https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/get-visible-lines-with-respect-to-current-scroll/1429

Edit:

Once you have a reference to a cell, it can be obtained like this:

```
(Cell<ICellModel>#editor as CodeMirrorEditor).editor
```

E.g.,

```
Notebook#widgets.forEach((cell: Cell<ICellModel>) => {
            (cell.editor as CodeMirrorEditor).editor // Editor
        });
```

Comment: How do you get CodeEditorWrapper instance?

Comment: @krassowski I found it here:  Cell<ICellModel>#editorWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you should need to use `CodeEditorWrapper` if you want to to get `CodeMirror` instance. For JupyterLab 3.0 the following should work well:

```
const cell: Cell = getTheCellObjectSomehow();
const editor = cell.editor as CodeMirrorEditor;
// or
// const fileEditor: FileEditor = getTheFileEditorObjectSomehow();
// const editor = cell.fileEditor as CodeMirrorEditor;
const cm: CodeMirror.Editor = cm.editor;
```

Where `cm` is your CodeMirror instance. If in doubt, consult how spellchecker extension ([here](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/spellchecker/blob/aff475d88bd2f1ded227e4f43eda9cef81db37dc/src/index.ts#L265-L268)) or lsp extension ([here](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/blob/39010530eba400bffc56282709343e9fcf8bc778/packages/jupyterlab-lsp/src/virtual/codemirror_editor.ts)) handle the CodeMirror access.

Comment: Sorry for ask, where you put that code?